# How do I prompt google calendar user to add a tag/description on a newly created event with app script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am trying to write a google apps script that prompts the user after new event created to add a tag to the event description or [extended property](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/extended-properties). I am thinking of using the [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar) along with the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/apps-script). It was easy enough to add an event to the calendar and list upcoming events like shown in the [advanced calendar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar) docs.

Is this however the best approach, as I would like the rest of the office to be able to use it with ease? The idea of it would be to serve as an add-on for users that they just add or install.

```
function theWatcher() {

  // The function that returns a new event added and prompts the user for a tag to be added to the description of the event
  var watcher = Calendar.Events.watch(resource, calendarId);

}
```

I am also having some issues with the watch function, I am not sure what the **resource** parameter should be. I believe it should be the email address and the **calendarId** should be "primary". However this gives me a parse error. Any idea Why?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Even just a point in the right direction. I have done thorough searching to find an answer to this but I seem to have some difficulty piecing it all together.
Please excuse my ignorance on this topic, I have only done some minor scripts to append sheets etc.

Comment: Did you just mix Calendar API with Apps Script? where did you get the  Calendar.Events.watch method?

Comment: Under the [Advanced Calendar Service] (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar) it states that it allows one to use the public google calendar API. It seems to be a built in service in Apps script.

Comment: I suspect that it is some form of class pointing to the users' calendar, I think it is stated [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/). The example in the Advanced Services link uses that same class/method to create and event. Also I seem to be able to use the Calendar method like this  ( gapi.client.calendar.events.list() ) in the external Javascript library, to print events between dates.